# How to read a config file such as json or ini in gatan script

Tags: dm-script

all:
I'd like to use the config file to flexibly set the strings and checkbox status in the UI. For example, the content in ini config file is like below:

[basic]

display_mag = False

display_scalebar = True

Now I used ReadFileLine to read the file content line by line. But I'd like to know whether there is better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your data is in the form of a text-based file, then ReadFileLine is really the only possible approach from within DM scripting. Text-based files can be in any number of formats, so one needs to parse each such line, which ultimately requires format-specific script code anyway.

Another option is to save configuration data in TagGroup files, which can be loaded and saved via the TagGroupLoadFromFile and TagGroupSaveToFile functions. However, these are not text-based and so cannot be edited with text editor programs. On the other hand, one can edit them within DM using the TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow(1) function applied to any TagGroup object loaded from a file. Details are covered in the Scripting>Objects>TagGroup Object section of DM's on-line help.

Comment: @ChenZX Yet another possibility is that perhaps someone has already created a DM-script library for parsing a particular text-based format, e.g. json, and loading the data into a TagGroup object, which can then be accessed from within a script via a corresponding tag label hierarchy. I'm not aware any such effort for json, but I have done this for XML files, in particular. If you are interested in such a library for XML, please contact me via the URL in my profile.

Comment: +1 to this answer. For GMS-UI based config - which will always be used in connection with GMS - I would recommend the TagGroup file solution. It offers the additional benefit that one can easily "transfer" the information between local files and the GMS internal preferences (GlobalTags) if one wants. A custom or standardized text-config file is really only of value if it needs to be used/edited outside GMS, but it has the danger of becoming "corrupt" if this external editing is done badly. Self-consistency checks on config read make for a large code overload that simply isn't there for Tags.

Comment: To add to the answer: The F1 help section (Scripting->Example Scripts->Tags,TagGroups and TagLists) is also a good starting point, showing how tagfiles can be used.